# how to take integers as command line arguments?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, getopt

I've read [a getopt() example](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt) but it doesn't show how to accept integers as argument options, like `cvalue` would be in the code from the example:

```
 #include <ctype.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

 int
 main (int argc, char **argv)
 {
   int aflag = 0;
   int bflag = 0;
   char *cvalue = NULL;
   int index;
   int c;

   opterr = 0;

   while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "abc:")) != -1)
     switch (c)
       {
       case 'a':
         aflag = 1;
         break;
       case 'b':
         bflag = 1;
         break;
       case 'c':
         cvalue = optarg;
         break;
       case '?':
         if (optopt == 'c')
           fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
         else if (isprint (optopt))
           fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
         else
           fprintf (stderr,
                    "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n",
                    optopt);
         return 1;
       default:
         abort ();
       }

   printf ("aflag = %d, bflag = %d, cvalue = %s\n",
           aflag, bflag, cvalue);

   for (index = optind; index < argc; index++)
     printf ("Non-option argument %s\n", argv[index]);
   return 0;
 }
```

If I ran the above as `testop -c foo`, `cvalue` would be `foo`, but what if I wanted `testop -c 42`? Since `cvalue` is of type `char *`, could I just cast `optarg` to be `(int)`? I've tried doing this without using `getopt()` and accessing `argv[whatever]` directly, and casting it as an integer, but I always end up with a large negative number when printing with `%d`. I'm assuming I'm not dereferencing `argv[]` correctly or something, not sure...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to use `atoi()` to convert from string to integer.

Answer (score 23):

All of the answers above are broadly correct (Vikram.exe gets props for explaining *why* you have to call a library function, which nobody else bothered to do).  However, nobody has named the *correct* library function to call.  Do not use `atoi`.  Do not use `sscanf`.

Use [`strtol`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol), or its relative [`strtoul`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul) if you don't want to allow negative numbers.  Only these functions give you enough information when the input was *not* a number.  For instance, if the user types

```
./a.out 123cheesesandwich
```

`atoi` and `sscanf` will cheerfully return 123, which is almost certainly not what you want.  Only `strtol` will tell you (via the `endptr`) that it processed only the first few characters of the string.

(There is no `strtoi`, but there is [`strtod`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod) if you need to read a floating-point number.)

Answer (score 11):

As you have already used in your code, the prototype for `main` function is

`int main (int argc, char** argv)`

What ever arguments are provided as command line arguments, they are passed to your 'program' as an array of char * (or simply strings). so if you invoke a prog as `foo.exe 123`, the first argument to `foo.exe` will be a string 123 and not an integer value of 123.

If you try casting the argument to integer (as you said) probably using some thing like: `(int) argv[1]`, you will not get the integer value of first argument, but some memory address where the first arg is stored in your address space. To get an integer value, you must explicitly convert string value to integer value. For this, you can use `atoi` function. Check [THIS](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) man page for similar functions that can be used for conversion.

Answer (score 5):

Use `atoi`.

```
cvalue = atoi( optarg );
```

And declare cvalue as an `int`.

Answer (score 4):

`atoi()`, which means ascii to integer is the function to use. Similarly, `atof()` can be used to get float values.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation i would go for a `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't just cast to convert it to an integer value. You need to transform it using sscanf, atoi, atol or similar function.